# Defining dynamically loaded class attributes with "dynamic" type

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, runtime

I'm loading an assembly generated on runtime that contains a class which has several attributes that need to be set.

From my research, I've found that this is possible using Reflection so here's how I load the assembly:

```
        Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("ClassLibrary1.dll");
        Type t = (Type)a.GetTypes()[0];
```

Now I'm trying to define properties this way:

```
        object ClassObj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        PropertyInfo p= t.GetProperties()[0];
        int x=1;
        p.SetValue(ClassObj,x);
```

This doesn't seem to viable for me so I thought of using the "dynamic" type.

```
        dynamic ClassObj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        ClassObj.soma = 1;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

It states that :

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'soma'
```

Is there anyway I can Map the class into the dynamic var?

Edit :

Fields of dynamic ClassObj show up "soma" propriety

Comment: Does `ClassObj` has `Soma` property as public?

Comment: Yes. It's a simple test class : 
public int soma { get; set; }

Comment: `dynamic` is case sensitive, are you sure the name of your property is not `Soma` ?

Comment: The property "Soma" was public. The class was not. I can now map the classes the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its works fine to me, try this:

```
    public class TypeTest
    {
        public string mimimi { get; set; }
    }

   Type t = typeof(TypeTest);
   dynamic instanceTypeTeste = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
   instanceTipoTeste.mimimi = "test";
```

**Possible problems in your code:**

- To change the value, property and class needs be `Public`
- The correct sintax, because the property name is Case Sensitive
- When you load a type, look if is the correct Type of your class

Comment: The class is loaded from a .dll file.

Comment: @user3466681 But the property "soma" is public?

Comment: @user3466681 does it not matter. The property "Soma" needs to be `Public`, if isn't you only alter the value by `PropertyInfo`

Comment: @user3466681 Have you sure that Assembly is not loading incorrect `Type` on the line `(Type)a.GetTypes()[0]`?

Comment: The property "Soma" was public. The class was not. That fixed the problem. Thank U!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `dynamic`, you have to be sure all the properties you're trying to access are written correctly. Or your property isn't `soma`, it might be `Soma` instead, or `Type t = (Type)a.GetTypes()[0];` isn't returning the type you expect.

I tried here with the same code, and when I tried to access a property with a different name, it threw the same exception.

You could also try to write all the path of your assembly:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\PathHere\ClassLibrary1.dll");
```

By the way, your class and properties must be public, otherwise you won't access it properly.